# Java code for Reading website which return either HTML or Text file

Tags: java, html, bufferedreader, filereader

I have few URLs which either return HTML code or text file. I got successful to grab the content of the URLs which return HTML file (as its easy too) but for other links which return txt file, I  don't know how to deal with them. Anybody on this?
Actually I have I have list of URLs in text file one per line which I read and want to crawl through every URL. I think I'll also need to implement some mechanism to differentiate between URLs on the basis of their return e.g either HTML or Text. Any references or examples?

Comment: why do not you use JSoup?

Comment: please structure the question properly. Hard to understand. What you mean by "I have few URLs"? Where you have them? in a web application?

please revise it.